# Display a datagrid cell in textbox

Tags: c#, datagrid, textbox

The app is done and works, pulls some info from SQL based off user defined filters and displays them in a datagrid view.  What I wanted to do however before calling it a day was this:

There is a column called "Comments".  Each row's entry has a comments cell.  I wanted to make it to that whenever you clicked on any row, the comments of that row's cell were displayed in a larger textbox I added above the datagrid.

I haven't worked with datagrid's until this project and after several hours of trial and error I figured was time to ask for help.

I'm not sure in this situation what existing code you may or may not need to assist but I will provide based on request.

Answer (score 0):

For a Winforms (WPF?) application, Use the RowEnter event:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  object commentObj = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Comments"].Value ; 
  commentTextBox.Text= commentObj==null ? "" : (string)commentObj ;
}
```

Comment: its a Windows Form Application.

Comment: I was able to modify and get working what you posted but sometimes it won't update the comment textbox with what's in the comment cell, sometimes I have to click the comments cell and other time it will allow me to click just the row (which I want).  not sure why its picking and choosing which ones and when to display.

Comment: I remenber that sometimes the RowEnter event is not raised just after initialisation or datsource modification. In this case, execute the RowEnter code for the First Row. After this init, RowEnter shall be executed each time a new row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have this below and it's just on and off sometimes I have to click a row then click away from it, then back onto it to get it to actually change to that rows comments otherwise it will still shows the comments of the previous rows

```
private void DataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {        
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = this.DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            txtComments.Text = row.Cells["Comments"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```